# nebula graph studio error when create tag from console link

Tags: nebula-graph, nebula-studio

I have nebula graph as many instance of dockers on my pc. this is my project,

I'm using nebula graph studio docker image to access data.

i can create tags and edges from java to this space and worked ok.

i want to browse my space

after connecting to nebula Studio http://localhost:7001 , I can create space for example: my_space and see my my_space_1

then I added tags via java and worked.

but in Studio when I want to create a tag : with this command

```
CREATE TAG school(name string , create_time timestamp);
```

nebula graph studio said:

DO NOT switch between graph spaces with nGQL statements in the console.

is there any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should select your space before run any ngql or cypher request

[image]